# How can i mix razor syntax and javascript syntax to change a hashtable value using a javascript var as key

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, asp.net-core, hashtable

I have a model in my application that has a hashtable. In my index.cshtml i want to set the value of a particular entry using javascript. Below is my piece of code:

```
$('input.optionselect').change(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        alert(@this.Model.checkHT[
                        @:id;
                        ] = false);
    });
```

i get the error:

Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: C# is rendered into a page once and only once, on the server. Once it is sent to the client the C# cannot ever be run again. JS is a client side language and therefore it cannot interact with the C# on the page since all expressions are already evaluated. The error you're getting is becasue `:id` is not defined by anything in the C#

Comment: Does that mean i can't alter the object that is passed to the model at all?

Comment: The only thing you can do with the objects in the Model is assign them to JS variables, you can then edit them through JS

Comment: is there an easy way to pass the entire hashtable from the model into a json object?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the hashtable as javascript object with this snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var hashtable = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.YourHashtable)
</script>
```

After that you will be able to access your data by value:

```
hashtable["sample"]
```